# Recuperar datos en mongoDB con Python filtrando por una lista de diccionarios

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

Tengo una lista similar a esta con las claves únicas de una tabla y necesito recuperar todos los registros de una tabla que tengan estas pk:

```
lista_pks = [
 {'pers_id': u'00000002', 'cod': u'0001'},
 {'pers_id': u'00000003', 'cod': u'0001'},
 {'pers_id': u'00000014', 'cod': u'0001'},
 {'pers_id': u'00000015', 'cod': u'0001'},
 {'pers_id': u'00000017', 'cod': u'0001'},
 {'pers_id': u'00000018', 'cod': u'0001'},
 {'pers_id': u'00000019', 'cod': u'0001'}
]
```

Hasta ahora solo tenía que filtra por valores concretos pero ahora necesito replicar algo como esto pero no consigo ver cómo podría hacerlo:

```
where (pers_id= '00000002' and cod= '0001') 
or (pers_id= '00000003' and cod= '0001') 
or (pers_id= '00000014' and cod= '0001') 
or (pers_id= '00000015' and cod= '0001') 
or (pers_id= '00000017' and cod= '0001') 
or (pers_id= '00000018' and cod= '0001') 
or (pers_id= '00000019' and cod= '0001')
```

¿Algún consejo sobre cómo enfocar la creación de esta consulta?

Answer (score 0):

He creado una función que tiene esta estructura, por las pruebas hechas funciona correctamente (aunque no sé si sigue siendo lo más óptimo...)

```
or_cond = {}
and_cond= list()
for dict_i in lista_pks:
    query_aux = {}
    query_aux['$and'] = [dict_i]
    and_cond.append(query_aux)

or_cond['$or'] = and_cond

Output:
{'$or': [{'$and': [{'pers_id': '00002', 'cod': '01'}]}, {'$and': [{'pers_id': '00003', 'cod': '01'}]}, {'$and': [{'pers_id': '00014', 'cod': '01'}]}, {'$and': [{'pers_id': '00015', 'cod': '01'}]}, {'$and': [{'pers_id': '00017', 'cod': '01'}]}, {'$and': [{'pers_id': '00018', 'cod': '01'}]}, {'$and': [{'pers_id': '00019', 'cod': '01'}]}]}
```